# How can I connect my additional field to database on Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, laravel-5.3

I have tried my code on register form.
When I click the register button, some error shows up.
Can you help me to solve this?
[Register Form Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeEUH.jpg)

[Error Message Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONb68.jpg)

migration create_user_table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'sometimes|required|max:255|unique:users',
        'email'    => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone'    => 'required',
        'terms'    => 'required',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $fields = [
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone'    => $data['phone'],
    ];
    if (config('auth.providers.users.field','email') === 'username' && isset($data['username'])) {
        $fields['username'] = $data['username'];
    }
    return User::create($fields);
}
```

And then on my register form:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}"/>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Comment: Can you do a `dd($fields)` just before the `User::create` and post the output along with your model code?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, in the Schema I would make the 'phone' field `->nullable()`, and add `->default(null)` too. Then, you could remove the `'phone' => 'required'` validation from the RegisterController.php file.